# Characters found after end of SQL statement VBA code Access 2007

Tags: sql, ms-access

I'm writing a VBA code in Excel to access an Access database.

I'm using this provider

```
"Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & DBFile & ";"
```

and here is my SQL string

```
SQlSrc = "SELECT YEAR FROM Data ORDER BY YEAR ASC"
SQlSrc = SQlSrc & ";SELECT STN FROM STN_List WHERE include = TRUE"
```

When I open each recordset individualy it works (just first line or second) but when I make as a single statement as above I get an error

> "Characters found after end of SQL statement"

Does anybody have idea if it's a problem with Access 2007?

Comment: Sounds like it's stopping SQL injection attacks by only allowing one statement to be executed.

Comment: Jet/ACE has never processed multiple SQL statements and never will, not to avoid SQL Injection (there are still plenty of SQL Injection types to which Jet/ACE is vulnerable), but because there is no server-side process to serialize SQL statements and interleave requests from multiple users.

Comment: @David W. Fenton: "because there is no server-side process to serialize SQL statements and interleave requests from multiple users" -- why do you think it needs one. You can do this client side e.g. using a ADODB Recordset with a batch optimistic locking, make changes then UpdateBatch. This has been supported from at least Jet 4.0. Why do you think this model shouldn't work?

Answer (score 2):

You can reuse the connection.

```
Dim cn As Object
Dim rs As Object

cn="Provider=Microsoft.ACE.OLEDB.12.0; Data Source= " & DBFile & ";"

SQlSrc = "SELECT YEAR FROM Data ORDER BY YEAR ASC"
rs.Open SQlSrc, cn

''Do stuff

SQlSrc = "SELECT STN FROM STN_List WHERE include = TRUE"
rs.Open SQlSrc, cn

cn.Execute "UPDATE Table SET Column=2"
```

Comment: Umm, not quite. The second invocation in your example is appending the second SQL query to the first one, bringing us back to where we started. It should just be a straight assignment, and lose the semicolon.

Answer (score 1):

It looks like Access and/or the provider doesn't accept multiple SQL statements for opening a single recordset.

That said, I'm not sure if this is standard for all OLEDB providers or just the one you're using.

Comment: Access has never supported more than one statment

Answer (score 1):

IMO MS Access does not support multiple SELECT statements in a single Command. You may have to split this into individual commands.